# CSS transitions 'spazing' some elements randomly on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

First of all, it is working 100% fine for me on Chrome, but works just as title described when on Firefox

I'm trying to make a simple animation (using transitions) to run indefinitely when mouseover and to slowly go back to initial position when mouseout

The problem is that it is not behaving the same way in Firefox

As requested, here's a minimized and simplified code that reproduces my current issue:

```js
var arcs = $("#logoSec");
var greenarc = $(".greenarc");

var garcMs = 2100; // In ms
var arcsAnimBool = false; // If false, stops the anim loop

greenarc.css({
  transition: "transform " + (garcMs * 1) + "ms ease-in-out"
});

function greenArcNormal() {
  if (!arcsAnimBool) return;
  greenarc.css("transform", "rotate(70deg)");
  setTimeout(greenArcRevert, garcMs); // Call the reverse rotation after garcMs ms
}

function greenArcRevert() {
  if (!arcsAnimBool) return;
  greenarc.css("transform", "rotate(-70deg)");
  setTimeout(greenArcNormal, garcMs); // Call the normal rotation after garcMs ms
}

arcs.hover(
  function() { // On mouseover
    arcsAnimBool = true;
    greenarc.css({
      transition: "transform " + (garcMs * 1) + "ms ease-in-out"
    });
    greenArcNormal();
  },
  function() { // On mouseout
    arcsAnimBool = false; // Set to false to stop the infinite loop of greenArcRevert/Normal
    greenarc.css("transform", "rotate(0deg)"); // Revert arc back to initial position
    greenarc.css({
      transition: "transform " + (garcMs * 0.5) + "ms ease-in-out"
    });
  }
);
```

```css
  #ArcsLogo {
    height: 550px;
  }

  #logoSec {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
  }
```

```html
<div id="logoSec">
  <svg class="arcs" version="1.1" id="ArcsLogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-12 30 383.4 407.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 383.4 407.5;" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
            .greenarc {
                fill: #00ff00;
                transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            }

            .graycircle {
                fill: #5d5d5d;
                transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            }

            .redarc {
                fill: #ff0000;
                transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            }
        </style>
        <path id="GreenArc" class="greenarc" d="M201.1,62.7c-3.2,0-6.3,0.1-9.4,0.3c77.7,5.5,136.2,72.9,130.7,150.6
                c-4.9,70-60.7,125.8-130.7,130.7c3.1,0.2,6.3,0.4,9.4,0.4c77.9,0,141-63.1,141-141S279,62.7,201.1,62.7L201.1,62.7z" />
        <circle id="GrayCircle" class="graycircle" cx="191.7" cy="203.7" r="21.2" />
        <path id="RedArc" class="redarc" d="M60.2,203.7c0-84.6,65.9-154.6,150.4-159.6c-3.1-0.2-6.3-0.3-9.5-0.3
                C112.8,43.2,40.7,114.2,40,202.5c-0.7,88.3,70.3,160.4,158.6,161.1c0.8,0,1.7,0,2.5,0c3.2,0,6.3-0.1,9.5-0.3
                C126.2,358.3,60.2,288.3,60.2,203.7z" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

(Simplified code in jsfiddle)
https://jsfiddle.net/Ferdam/htxcwanu/28/

(Old full code: https://jsfiddle.net/Ferdam/9kz52e6h/3/)

I have little experience with HTML/JS/JQuery/CSS so I might be missing something basic, I don't know.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

Quoting directly what I answered to nivoli:

> I forgot to mention that I tried using keyframes before, but the
>   problem is that I couldn't get it to work like the code I provided
>   because whenever I hoverout the elements just 'teleport' back to
>   initial position, which is why I started using css transitions. 
>   I just couldn't find a way to animate the elements back to initial position
>   using keyframes

Comment: Try to isolate more your issue, remove everything that is not related to the issue, and come back with an [MCVE]. At the end, maybe a single element with a single rule will appear has being the culprit, but for now, there are too much work for us just to dig it.

Comment: Here is an MCVE: https://jsfiddle.net/v1jd5y7L/ feel free to [edit] your question and use it instead. And I am sorry I don't have time anymore to dig the issue for now...

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry about that. I'll edit the code shortly to provide a minimal version of it

Comment: I've found time to edit my post and include a simpler code that still has the same issue as the old full code I posted before

Answer (score 2):

No javascript necessary; just use [css animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations). I only did the green one for you:

```css
#ArcsLogo {
  height: 550px;
}

#logoSec {
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

.greenarc {
  fill: #00ff00;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(70deg);
  animation: myRotate 4200ms alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}

.graycircle {
  fill: #5d5d5d;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.redarc {
  fill: #ff0000;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes myRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(70deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-70deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="logoSec">
  <svg class="arcs" version="1.1" id="ArcsLogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-12 30 383.4 407.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 383.4 407.5;" xml:space="preserve">
        <path id="GreenArc" class="greenarc" d="M201.1,62.7c-3.2,0-6.3,0.1-9.4,0.3c77.7,5.5,136.2,72.9,130.7,150.6
                c-4.9,70-60.7,125.8-130.7,130.7c3.1,0.2,6.3,0.4,9.4,0.4c77.9,0,141-63.1,141-141S279,62.7,201.1,62.7L201.1,62.7z" />
        <circle id="GrayCircle" class="graycircle" cx="191.7" cy="203.7" r="21.2" />
        <path id="RedArc" class="redarc" d="M60.2,203.7c0-84.6,65.9-154.6,150.4-159.6c-3.1-0.2-6.3-0.3-9.5-0.3
                C112.8,43.2,40.7,114.2,40,202.5c-0.7,88.3,70.3,160.4,158.6,161.1c0.8,0,1.7,0,2.5,0c3.2,0,6.3-0.1,9.5-0.3
                C126.2,358.3,60.2,288.3,60.2,203.7z" />
    </svg>


</div>
```

They key is to define the `keyframes`, which I just copied from the `transform` declarations you were making in javascript. Then by adding the `animation` rule to the `greenarc` class, we tell it to

- use the keyframes `myRotate` (change the name to whatever you want)
- take `4200ms` to move from `0%` to `100%`. I doubled it because I think your logic took `2100ms` to move from `rotate(0)` to `rotate(70)`.
- `alternate` the direction of the animation so that it goes back-and-forth rather than moving in one direction, then snapping back to where it started.
- repeat the animation `infinite`ly
- use `ease-in-out` as you were doing in javascript to slow down as it gets closer to the ends.

See the animation documentation for more details and examples.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried using keyframes before, but the problem is that I couldn't get it to work like the code I provided because whenever I hoverout the elements just 'teleport' back to initial position, which is why I started using css transitions
I just couldn't find a way to animate the elements back to initial position using keyframes